# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT webname, description,weburl,image FROM work where id=:action")) {



    // Bind a variable to the parameter as a string. 
    $stmt->bind_param(':action', $action);

    // Execute the statement.
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the variables from the query.
    $stmt->bind_result($row);

    // Fetch the data.
    $stmt->fetch();



    // Close the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use MySQLi method names on PDO objects...

Comment: `bind_param` is mysqli function. Make sure you know what you're doing here.